# How to access bound classes from a `py::module` object?

Tags: c++, oop, pybind11

When using `pybind11` to expose some C++ code, is there a way to access defined classes (`py::class`) from the module object (`py::module`)?  I understand I can use `attr` directly from a bound class, but can I do the same for classes from a module?

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/operators.h>


class MyClass {
 public:
    MyClass() = default;
    // ...
};

class MyOtherClass {
 public:
    MyOtherClass() = default;
    // ...
    MyClass val;
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

template < typename T >
py::class_< T > bind(py::module& module, const char* name);


template < >
py::class_< MyClass > bind(py::module& module, const char* name) {
    return py::class_< MyClass >(module, name)
        .def(py::init< >(), "Constructs a new instance")
        // ...
        .def("__repr__", [](const MyClass& obj) { return "something"; });
}

template < >
py::class_< MyOtherClass > bind(py::module& module, const char* name) {
    return py::class_< mmyClas >(module, name)
        .def(py::init< >(), "Constructs a new instance")
        // ...
        .def("__repr__", [](const MyOtherClass& obj) { return module.class("MyClass").attr("__repr__")(obj.val); });   //  <- how to call "__repr__" defined for MyClass ?
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

PYBIND11_MODULE(pymodule, module) {
    // ...
    bind< MyClass >(module, "MyClass");
    bind< MyOtherClass >(module, "MyOtherClass");
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combing through [pybind11's documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html), I was able to find [the answer](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html#accessing-the-type-object):

```
py::type T_py = py::type::of<T>();
```

I can then call the `__repr__` method on an object:

```
py::type::of< MyClass >().attr("__repr__")(obj);
```

which can be made into a generic function template:

```
template < typename T >
inline std::string repr(const T& in) {
    return py::str(py::type::of< T >().attr("__repr__")(in));
}
```

to simplify the syntax when binding multiple dependent types independently (*i.e.* without access to `py::class_<>` instances).

Note: `repr()` will raise an `ImportError` on Python in case `T` hasn't been exposed to Python.